# What caused the program to stop working correctly?

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, troubleshooting

Error message "a problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program"

I upgraded my computer from Windows 7 to 8 pro on my new Lenovo PC.
Ever since the upgrad I am getting this error message as a pop up, on its own. Even if my system is in idle. (I mean its in desktop mode. even before any application has started.)

It will either give me an option to close or debug. If I hit debug, it will try to start visual studio and that will crash too with the same error message.

I also receive the same error message every time I try to start a few applications like Internet explorer, Remote Desktop Connection etc.. But if I run them as an Administrator it will start running.

I Checked the event viewer when I start the internet explorer and this is the error message from event viewer.

```
Faulting application name: iexplore.exe, version: 10.0.9200.16537, time stamp: 0x5123410e
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000007fa0e790000
Faulting process id: 0x1e30
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce5425ec75a441
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 2a2329a8-c019-11e2-bea8-047d7b4222c5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

How can I fix this issue? I already tried reinstalling windows 8.

Comment: I'm inclined to suspect a driver issue. did the manufacturer publish drivers for windows 8 on your laptop? does it happen in ie safemode? an exception of 0xc0000005 means access is denied to somthing, but what it is, the message does not say.

Comment: is this an overmoderated place here. Here are the steps: http://pastebin.com/SxrK4LWY.

Comment: http://sdrv.ms/14HxyE2 - here is the dump. Thanks

Comment: I got the dump. read my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i check the dump with WinDbg and saw that the file ActiveDetect64.dll from **Lenovo Onekey Theater** seams to cause the crash:

```
FAULTING_IP: 
+0
000007fa`0e790000 48ff25b5b21100  jmp     qword ptr [gdi32!langToDigitScript+0xc7ac (000007fa`0e8ab2bc)]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fa0e790000
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffffffffff
Attempt to read from address ffffffffffffffff

PROCESS_NAME:  iexplore.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  ffffffffffffffff

READ_ADDRESS:  ffffffffffffffff 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ActiveDetect64!RemoveR3APIHook64+7c
0000004b`856c2c4c 4889442420      mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax

NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000100

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  48004

APP:  iexplore.exe

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000001ce4

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_EXPLOITABLE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_EXPLOITABLE

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_EXPLOITABLE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000004b856c2c4c to 000007fa0e790000

STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
verifier!AVrfpNtWaitForMultipleObjects
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
verifier!AVrfpWaitForMultipleObjectsExCommon
verifier!AVrfpKernelbaseWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
kernel32!WerpReportFault
KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter
ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
ntdll!_C_specific_handler
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
0x0
ActiveDetect64!RemoveR3APIHook64
ieframe!__delayLoadHelper2
ieframe!_tailMerge_urlmon_dll
ieframe!_SetMatchFromContext
ieframe!LCIEMergeFrameProcess
ieframe!LCIEStartAsFrame
ieframe!DesktopFrameProcess
iexplore!wWinMain
iexplore!__wmainCRTStartup
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  activedetect64!RemoveR3APIHook64+7c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ActiveDetect64

IMAGE_NAME:  ActiveDetect64.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d5b5e93

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_EXPLOITABLE_c0000005_ActiveDetect64.dll!RemoveR3APIHook64

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_EXPLOITABLE_activedetect64!RemoveR3APIHook64+7c

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/iexplore_exe/10_0_9200_16537/5123410e/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/c0000005/0e790000.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0:000> lmvm ActiveDetect64
start             end                 module name
0000004b`856c0000 0000004b`85714000   ActiveDetect64   (export symbols)       ActiveDetect64.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: ActiveDetect64.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Onekey Theater\ActiveDetect64.dll
    Image name: ActiveDetect64.dll
    Timestamp:        Wed Feb 16 06:20:19 2011 (4D5B5E93)



HostMachine\HostUser
Executing Processor Architecture is x64
Debuggee is in User Mode
Debuggee is a user mode small dump file
Event Type: Exception
Exception Faulting Address: 0xffffffffffffffff
Second Chance Exception Type: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xC0000005)
Exception Sub-Type: Read Access Violation

Faulting Instruction:000007fa`0e790000 jmp qword ptr [gdi32!langtodigitscript+0xc7ac (000007fa`0e8ab2bc)]

Exception Hash (Major/Minor): 0x851865ef.0x8ad69e1c

 Hash Usage : Stack Trace:
Major+Minor : Unknown
Major+Minor : ActiveDetect64!RemoveR3APIHook64+0x7c
Major+Minor : ieframe!__delayLoadHelper2+0x1ca
Major+Minor : ieframe!_tailMerge_urlmon_dll+0x3f
Major+Minor : ieframe!_SetMatchFromContext+0x3f
Minor       : ieframe!LCIEMergeFrameProcess+0x5a
Minor       : ieframe!LCIEStartAsFrame+0x184
Minor       : ieframe!DesktopFrameProcess+0x3a
Minor       : iexplore!wWinMain+0x5f4
Minor       : iexplore!__wmainCRTStartup+0x1b2
Minor       : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x1a
Minor       : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
Instruction Address: 0x000007fa0e790000

Description: Read Access Violation on Control Flow
Short Description: ReadAVonControlFlow
Exploitability Classification: EXPLOITABLE
Recommended Bug Title: Exploitable - Read Access Violation on Control Flow starting at Unknown Symbol @ 0x000007fa0e790000 called from ActiveDetect64!RemoveR3APIHook64+0x000000000000007c (Hash=0x851865ef.0x8ad69e1c)

Access violations not near null in control flow instructions are considered exploitable.
```

so look for an update or remove this extension, because this crash may be exploitable.

Comment: is the issue now fixed?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I uninstalled Lenova one key. I am still getting the same error. I can post the new dump if you want. or can you let me know which editor should I use to open the dmp file? Thanks.

Comment: post the new dumps.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. I didnt get a chance to play with it.. I am still having the same issues.. http://sdrv.ms/17mHRzn here is my new dump.

Comment: still the same. The **ActiveDetect64.dll** is the cause.

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve it. Is there anything else apart from Lenova one key, that I have to uninstall..

Comment: remove this Lenovo tool. If you already did this, delete the DLL from **C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Onekey Theater**